# Example of nanomsg crate does not work

Tags: rust, nanomsg

I tried the Rust nanomsg  [pubsub example](https://github.com/thehydroimpulse/nanomsg.rs/blob/master/examples/pubsub.rs), but it does not work.

I did each of these operations in separate console windows:

1. `cargo run --example pubsub -- device hoge`

   It shows

   ```
   Subscribed to '[104, 111, 103, 101]'.
   Device is ready.
   ```
2. `cargo run --example pubsub -- client hoge`

   It shows

   ```
   Subscribed to '[104, 111, 103, 101]'.
   ```
3. `cargo run --example pubsub -- server hoge`

   It shows

   ```
   Server is ready.
   Published '[104, 111, 103, 101] #1'.
   Published '[104, 111, 103, 101] #2'.
   Published '[104, 111, 103, 101] #3'.
   ...
   ```

All three commands kept running, none of them exited. I expected console 2 to show:

```
Subscribed to '[104, 111, 103, 101]'.
Recv '[104, 111, 103, 101] #1'.
Recv '[104, 111, 103, 101] #2'.
Recv '[104, 111, 103, 101] #3'.
...
```

But nothing was displayed.

My environment is

- Max OS X Sierra
- nanomsg 1.0.0
- rustc 1.16.0

Comment: I can reproduce this. To be honest, it could really be a problem with the actual example, so I filed an issue: https://github.com/thehydroimpulse/nanomsg.rs/issues/173

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was an issue with the server code, which has already been fixed in the master branch ([#173](https://github.com/thehydroimpulse/nanomsg.rs/issues/173)). Here's the faulty snippet ([from repo](https://github.com/blabaere/nanomsg.rs/blob/a9d46929119ce0dd437caf4e651b4f5d273eae50/examples/pubsub.rs#L50)):

```
let msg = format!("{:?} #{}", topic,  count);
match socket.write_all(msg.as_bytes()) {
    Ok(..) => println!("Published '{}'.", msg),
    Err(err) => {
        println!("Server failed to publish '{}'.", err);
        break
    }
}
```

The published message was built using the `format!` macro, which was improperly pretty-printing the topic as an array of bytes, rather than a slice of text. A different topic identifier led to no subscribers receiving the message.

The example was fixed [here](https://github.com/thehydroimpulse/nanomsg.rs/blob/6fe241d9551c4f67e54d0df67c4d4d9f1da53f74/examples/pubsub.rs#L51-L55) by the current maintainer. As an ending note, users of this API have to keep in mind that the first bytes of a publish message always refer to the subscription topic.